# Extend interface and extract original interface again

Tags: typescript, redux

What I am trying to do is extending an interface, that might or might not have a "payload" property like this:

```
type Extended<T> = T extends { payload: any }
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]: K extends 'payload'
      ? { id: string; originalPayload: T[K] }
      : T[K]
    }
  : T & { payload: { id: string } }
```

What I am trying to accomplish with this is having a "payload" property on the new type of the form

```
interface Payload {
  id: string;
  originalPayload?: "typeof originalPayload" // only if there was an original payload
}
```

Later in the code, I want to extract the "id" prop from the new type and regain the old type with something like

```
const { payload: { id, originalPayload = undefined }, ...rest } = varOfNewType
const varOfOldType = {
  ...rest,
  ...(originalPayload !== undefined ? { payload: originalPayload } : {}),
}
```

But I get an error similar to

> Property 'originalPayload' does not exist on type 'T extends { payload: any; } ? { id: string; originalPayload: T["payload"]; } : { id: string; }'.

I am totally lost and have no idea how to get this right. Also tried it differently, e.g like

```
type Extended<T> = { [prop in Exclude<keyof T, 'payload'>]: T[prop] } & {
  payload: T extends { payload: any }
    ? { id: string; originalPayload: T['payload'] }
    : { id: string };
};
```

but nothing works. :(

**To give some context:** *I am playing around with Redux and have a flat state with "collections", which are maps of the kind `id => Entity`. I also have reducers for single Entities. I try to compose a collection reducer that invokes the single entity reducer on the entity with the right id and just returns all the other entities in the collection as they are. For that I need to enrich the original action so it has the id in its payload and then get back the original action to hand over to the single entity reducer.*

I would love to either find a solution for my original problem or receive suggestions for a better approach on what I am trying to do in general. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If you are doing this inside a generic function, conditional types don't do well there since they still contain unresolved type parameters. Inside the generic function you might need some type assertions.

Comment: When I tried to assert that I am not dealing with an empty object or something, it was not helping unfortunately. I tried testing for `Object.keys(remainingPayload}.length > 0` e.g. to assert that the remaining payload `const { id, ...remainingPayload } = payload` was not an empty object. remainingPayload was still shown as {} | ... type inside the if block.